# Is this relation total?

Tags: relations

It's not clear to me why this relation is not total:

$\{(x,y)|x=y\}$

The way I interpret this is, since x = y, it is always true that (x,y) or (y,x) is part of the relation. Doesn't this imply that the relation is total?

Comment: What is the definition of total?

Comment: Either (x,y) or (y,x) has to be part of the relation, for all vertices x and y

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.  Suppose $x=2$ and $y=3$.  Neither $(2,3)$ nor $(3,2)$ are members of the relation.

Comment: But x has to be equal to y in order for the tuple to be part of the relation, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Looks like you're reasoning is circular.  Your argument seems to be the following: If $(x,y)$ is in the relation, then $x=y$ which means that $(x,y)$ is in the relation. But you assume $(x,y)$ was in the relationship to begin with.